# Python pip run but dont see anything when running

Tags: python, pip

i use python 2.7.10 and window 7. When i use "pip" to install new package, i don't see anything when it run like this:
[install pillow using pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL6w4.png)

Can anybody tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Does it actually install the package?

Comment: yes, it does. But i dont see output in cmd

Comment: Can you show us the command you run here, without linking to it? Can you show what you would expect to see, what you actually see?

Comment: this is result when i run pip. http://i.stack.imgur.com/gL6w4.png and i expect to see something like this https://youtu.be/lDMhghF-9Vk?t=114

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PIP uses a configuration file called `pip.ini`, in which you can set default command-line options for PIP. Chances are the `--quiet` option is turned on by default; this option causes PIP to produce no output unless there's an error, just like in your case.

There are multiple places that it could be:

- C:\Users\you\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini
- C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini

You need to edit your file (if they're both present, edit both) to remove the lines that look like one of the following:

- `quiet = true` / `on` / `yes`
- `q = true` / `on` / `yes`

Save the file(s) and you should then see output from PIP the next time you run it.

### If there's no `pip.ini`

If you can't  find a `pip.ini` file anywhere, create one in:

C:\Users\you\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini

Open it using a text editor, then put this inside it:

```
[global]
quiet = false
```

### Demonstration

Here's a GIF demonstrating the difference between `--quiet` and no `--quiet`:

[image]

Comment: i cant see the file configure pip.ini anywhere

Comment: Slightly offtopic, but what did you use to make the gif? it's really handy

Comment: yes. I see. But i go to my %USERPROFILE%, i don't see pip folder then i create new pip folder, next i create new file pip.ini and write something like you do but it still not be @OrangeFlash81

Comment: @SimonFraser I used ShareX. Right click the taskbar icon > Capture > Screen recording (GIF). It even uploads it to Imgur automatically!

Comment: @vũHiếu Trying putting it in %APPDATA% instead. Again, you might need to create a folder.

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 Thank you!